# How can I obfuscate SQL code for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate my SQL code for PostgreSQL (which saved as `.sql` files). But can't find clear way to do it.

These SQL code should be run with `psql` on Linux system.

The point of this obfuscation job is making SQL code hard-readable on customer side.

I tried to use shell script binary generator (shc) to obfuscate the whole queries, but that didn't really work well.

Are there any things to try more?

Need your help.

Comment: That won't work. Either you trust your customers, or you do stuff on your own servers. Obfuscating or encrypting SQL on their servers makes no sense: anything obfuscated can be deobfuscated, and in the end they just need to turn on PostgreSQL query logging to completely ignore any attempts at encryption you may employ.

Comment: like @Amadan saids obfuscation adds a "small" to "medium" protection depending on the programmers skill to reverse engineer.. A good programmer/reverse engineer can most likely figure out what the obfuscated  code means so it is pretty much [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am not a freelance worker, and this is our company product. We just sell our "product", not an access to code. They are separated things. I understand what you said but that is completely useless offtopic in this case.

Comment: Fair enough i removed the legal comment.. i search some on the internet the only thing i found which was somehow helpfull was https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/162867790801280451y5ca29f00i1a55e8673ba80e5@mail.gmail.com .. Some downsides it only works on functions.. there is a deobfuscate password which a admin off a server could read..if you would to change it you would need to know how to program c/c++ and how to compile plus the customer would have to use your compiled PostgreSQL server application instead

Comment: Or you would need to make a dynamic plug-in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html which can be dynamicly loaded